# get current location from GPS in Blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, gps, blackberry-storm, locationmanager

How to get current location from GPS in Blackberry application. I tried to get location from `Locationmanager method` in simulator its work fine but in my device (Storm 2 using wifi) I am not able to get current lat long.

my code

```
    private class LocationListenerImpl implements LocationListener {  
    public void locationUpdated(LocationProvider provider, Location location) {  
        if (location.isValid()) {  
            heading = location.getCourse();  
            longitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude();  
            latitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude();  
            altitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getAltitude();  
            speed = location.getSpeed();  

            // This is to get the Number of Satellites  
            String NMEA_MIME = "application/X-jsr179-location-nmea";  
            satCountStr = location.getExtraInfo("satellites");  
            if (satCountStr == null) {  
                satCountStr = location.getExtraInfo(NMEA_MIME);  
            }  

            // this is to get the accuracy of the GPS Cords  
            QualifiedCoordinates qc = location.getQualifiedCoordinates();  
            accuracy = qc.getHorizontalAccuracy();  
        }  
    }  

    public void providerStateChanged(LocationProvider provider, int newState) {  
        // no-op  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Not enough information about your problem - is GPS turned on? does your code conform to the blackberry way? are there permissions required of the application that you don't request?

Comment: GPS is enable . yes code is in blackberry way and its working in simulator after send lat long from GPS system . and the third about permission ? i have no idea wich permission you r talking ?

Comment: if you have any idea , help me

Comment: @Hitarth: In device Options (on my Storm 9530 simulator it is in the 'Options' -> 'Security Options' -> 'Application Permissions' -> select your app -> 'Edit Permissions' menu item) the permissoin for this is named as "Location Data".

Answer (score 1):

I found this on the first place I looked for storm issues : `If you run the above code on your BlackBerry device (for instance a Storm), you will get a "GPS not allowed" LocationProvider exception. You need to get your code signed if you want to use the BlackBerry Storm with GPS in your app. To do this, you need to buy a $20 certificate from RIM.`

Comment: my code is already singed . hole application works fine in device . my application have one button that name  "Use Current location" get current location from this button click event and go ahead for the application but in device every time i get 0.0 lat and long .i have storm 2 without sim card i am using hole application using wifi.

Comment: my hole day west to solve that problem but i cant get solution .. if you have any demo or suggetion regarding same please help me

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235660/setlocationlistener-not-working-in-blackberry-gps-programming